# Meteor: SCSS/SASS not loading after meteor update

Tags: meteor, sass

I updated my meteor project to meteor 0.9.1 today. Previously I had a simple SCSS file with variables.

```
/*variables*/

$font: 200 20px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
$color: #312F47;
```

After the update none of the scss seems to be implemented on the page (background-color is reverted to white for instance and all the styling elements are gone). Manually converting the scss to css does work. I have tried updated the various packages to no avail. Does anyone know if this is a known bug and/or how to fix this? Would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed you're using mrt:scss, and according to [mrt:scss package page on Atmosphere](http://atmospherejs.com/mrt/scss), it's currently **INCOMPATIBLE WITH METEOR 0.9.0 OR LATER**.

You need to replace mrt:scss with [fourseven:scss](http://atmospherejs.com/fourseven/scss) which is the same package compatible with Meteor 0.9.0 or later with a new name, since 0.9.0 is using Meteor packaging system and mrt is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed fixed the problem